# Stop $.each, load image and then continue loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I need to stop $.each loop, load image and then continue loop. I have canvas where I load images of objects. Objects are in array in correctly order. Now, when I'm trying to load objects from array, there is a problem: images are loading slower or faster because of different sizes and they're drawing on canvas e.g. in reversed order. I hope you will understand me because my English isn't so good. Good luck anyway :)

```
    $.each(content,function(i){
        obj_id[i] = $.inArray( content[i], different_objects ) != -1 ? time == "day" ? content[i] + 'd' : content[i] : content[i];
        temp[i] = new Image();
        temp[i].src = '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i;
        $(temp[i]).on('load', function() {
            city_cvs.drawImage({
                layer: true,
                source: '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i,
                x: offset + x + content_pause, y: y - temp[i].height,
                fromCenter: false,
                opacity: opacity
            });

            offset = offset + temp[i].width + content_pause;
        });
    });
```

Comment: how have you defined `content`? and when or where are you calling the `$.each()` function?

Comment: @AminJafari I'm getting content from database and split to array `content = content.split(",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you start all the images loading (for max performance) and then you add some logic to make sure you draw them in order when they arrive - drawing as many sequential images that you haven't yet drawn on each onload event.  Here's how to do that:

```
var images = [];
var lastDrawn = -1;
$.each(content,function(i){
    obj_id[i] = $.inArray( content[i], different_objects ) != -1 ? time == "day" ? content[i] + 'd' : content[i] : content[i];
    var img = new Image();
    // put empty image slot in the array
    images[i] = null;
    img.onload = function() {
        // mark this one as loaded now
        images[i] = this;
        // now draw all sequential images since lastDrawn that are ready
        // code will stop drawing when it encounters an image that is not yet ready
        for (var imageIndex = lastDrawn + 1; imageIndex < images.length; imageindex++) {
            // if the image in this slot is ready, draw it
            if (images[imageIndex]) {
                city_cvs.drawImage({
                    layer: true,
                    source: images[imageIndex].src,
                    x: offset + x + content_pause, y: y - images[imageIndex].height,
                    fromCenter: false,
                    opacity: opacity
                });
                // update the lastDrawn index
                lastDrawn = imageIndex;
            } else {
                // found an image that is not yet ready so stop drawing for now
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // must set .src property AFTER the onload handler is set (IE will fire onload immediately if the image is cached
    img.src = '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling your function recursively after the image was loaded :

```
(function loopFunction(i){

    obj_id[i] = $.inArray( content[i], different_objects ) != -1 ? time == "day" ? content[i] + 'd' : content[i] : content[i];
    temp[i] = new Image();
    temp[i].src = '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i;
    $(temp[i]).on('load', function() {
        city_cvs.drawImage({
            layer: true,
            source: '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i,
            x: offset + x + content_pause, y: y - temp[i].height,
            fromCenter: false,
            opacity: opacity
        });

        offset = offset + temp[i].width + content_pause;
        if(i<content.length) loopFunction(i++); // Call again
    });

})(0); // <-- i = 0
```

Comment: This is a pretty slow way to go because you don't get any parallel loading.  You don't even start loading the next image until the last one finished.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I tried this way, but images are loading too long. Thanks Oliboy50 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
var counter=0;
function loading(i){
    obj_id[i] = $.inArray( content[i], different_objects ) != -1 ? time == "day" ? content[i] + 'd' : content[i] : content[i];
    temp[i] = new Image();
    temp[i].src = '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i;
    $(temp[i]).on('load', function() {
        city_cvs.drawImage({
            layer: true,
            source: '../data/img/objects/' + obj_id[i] + '.png?' + i,
            x: offset + x + content_pause, y: y - temp[i].height,
            fromCenter: false,
            opacity: opacity
        });

        offset = offset + temp[i].width + content_pause;
    });
    counter++;
    if(content[counter].length!=0){
        content[counter].load(loading(counter));
    }
};
content[0].load(loading(counter));
```

Comment: I changed a bit your code because of errors, `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ` and `Cannot read property 'load' of undefined`. Here is part of your code I changed: `if(counter < content.length) { loading(counter); }` It works without errors but problem of reversed order still exits. :(

Comment: So, you fixed some errors, but the main problem of drawing order is still not addressed?